# Sequoyah Eclipse plugin: "Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency" error

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to install the Sequoyah Eclipse plugin. I use the normal procedure:

1. Help=>Add new software
2. I enter the URL "http://download.eclipse.org/sequoyah/updates/2.0/"
3. I select the package I want to install ("Sequoyah Android Native Code Support")
4. And click "Next"

I get the following error:

```
*The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Sequoyah Android Native Code Support 1.1.2.N20110726-1041 (org.eclipse.sequoyah.android.cdt.feature.feature.group 1.1.2.N20110726-1041)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools 6.0.0.200909110608 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 6.0.0.200909110608)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    CDT Build System Core 7.0.1.201009141542 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 7.0.1.201009141542)
    CDT Build System Core 7.0.2.201102110609 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 7.0.2.201102110609)
    CDT Build System Core 6.0.0.200909110608 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 6.0.0.200909110608)
    CDT Build System Core 6.0.0.201002161416 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 6.0.0.201002161416)
    CDT Build System Core 7.0.0.201006141710 (org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 7.0.0.201006141710)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools 6.0.0.200909110608 (org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group 6.0.0.200909110608)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group [6.0.0.200909110608]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse C/C++ Development Platform 6.0.0.200909110608 (org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group 6.0.0.200909110608)
    To: org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core [6.0.0.200909110608]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Sequoyah Android Native Support UI 1.1.2.N20110726-1041 (org.eclipse.sequoyah.android.cdt.build.ui 1.1.2.N20110726-1041)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core 7.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Sequoyah Android Native Code Support 1.1.2.N20110726-1041 (org.eclipse.sequoyah.android.cdt.feature.feature.group 1.1.2.N20110726-1041)
    To: org.eclipse.sequoyah.android.cdt.build.ui [1.1.2.N20110726-1041]*
```

Anybody knows how to solve this issue ?

Thanks !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved my issue !

As mentioned in the error message, I had to uninstall the "Eclipse C/C++ Development Tools" following this procedure: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_remove_a_plug-in%3F

Then I installed Sequoyah.

Hope this helps.